# How to execute go get from other directory?

Tags: bash, go

I'm writing an alias (unix) which will update a git repository and then call `go get -d ./...` (to load all dependencies).

Is there a way to call something like in git (below)?

```
git -C /my/path/with/git/repo pull origin master
```

In short, is there a way to pass in the context directory of a command to `go get`?

Comment: `go get` works in `GOPATH`, it doesn't matter where you call it from, just use a package name instead of `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a `cd` commad before the `go get` in your alias:

```
alias x="(cd /path/to/repo; go get -d ./...)"
```

**Don't forget the parentheses**, or you'll have to `cd` back to the original directory.

Comment: I did. But now I have to go back to the original path in the end and I dont know if its possible to save a tmp variable with the old path

Comment: @Th3B0Y no you don't have to. Remember to put it inside parentheses like I did.